# angularjs-slider/rz-module: change end label value

Tags: angularjs

Does anybody know how to change the end labeled value of [rzModule/angular-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider)? I've looked into the documentation and example but couldn't find so.

> 0 ---------------------- 500

like below, i just want to add '+' at the end of last value.

> 0 ---------------------- 500+

So that means it is more than 500

html:

```
<div>
    <rzslider rz-slider-model="vm.slider_callbacks.value" rz-slider-options="vm.slider_callbacks.options"></rzslider>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
vm.slider_callbacks = {
            value: 100,
            options: {
                floor: 0,
                ceil: 500,
                step: 5,
                showSelectionBar: true,
                onEnd: function (id, newValue, highValue, pointerType) {
                    vm.radius = newValue >= 500 ? 9999 : newValue;
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do workaround, after initialisation of slider you can target particular label of slider by jquery or javascript and change it's text e.g.

`if(newValue >= 500){$('.rz-bubble').text('500+');}`